# How do I disable drag and drop on GNOME/Ubuntu dock?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

Currently I'm searching for an option to disable the drag and drop function on the dock but in the GUI Setting I didn't found an option for this.

Is there a way to disable this?